# How to upload all csv files that have specific name inside filename in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to concat all csv file that have this specific word 'tables' on the filename.
Below code is upload all csv file without filter the specific word that i want.

```
# importing the required modules
import glob
import pandas as pd
  
# specifying the path to csv files
#path = "csvfoldergfg"
path = "folder_directory"

# csv files in the path
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")


# defining an empty list to store 
# content
data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
content = []

# checking all the csv files in the 
# specified path
for filename in files:
    
    # reading content of csv file
    # content.append(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    content.append(df)
    

# converting content to data frame
data_frame = pd.concat(content)
print(data_frame)
```

example filename are: 
abcd-tables.csv 
abcd-text.csv 
abcd-forms.csv 
defg-tables.csv 
defg-text.csv 
defg-forms.csv

From the example filenames. The expected output is concat filenames 
abcd-tables.csv 
defg-tables.csv 
into single dataframe. Assuming the header are same.

*Really appreciate you guys can solve this

Comment: read up on `glob.glob`. You're gonna kick yourself when you see how easy this is

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

path = 'folder_directory'
content = []
for filename in pathlib.Path(path).glob('*-tables.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    content.append(df)
df = pd.concat(content, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien . I do try run your code. But the output is not what I want. I want to select all  csv file that have specific keyword on the filenames itself. Example filename= abcd-tables.csv .

Comment: `'*tables*.csv'` should match `'abcd-tables.csv'`

Comment: I fixed some errors. Can you check it please? I also updated my answer with another version.

Comment: Hi @Corralien. Thank you for do fixed some errors. However the output not what i want. Btw, I already update the question with the expected output that i want. Really appreciate you see it.

Comment: Try `path.glob('*-tables.csv')`. I tried with your filenames and it worked.

Comment: I got error--> 'str' object has no attribute 'glob'

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you forgot to use `path = pathlib.Path('folder_directory')` in the previous version so I changed it to this last version.